# Convert Json response to HTML Table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, json

How do I display all the points in this Json return statement to an HTML table on my view?

```
return Json(
    new
    {
        vol = exposure.Volatility,
        points =
            from point in exposure.ExposurePointCollection
            select new
            {
                date = point.ExposureDate,
                val = point.MaximumExposure
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the result of an ajax call, you will need to iterate over the collection (presumably the "points" value) and add them to the DOM via javascript.  jQuery can help with this, but there are also plug-ins for jQuery that will do virtually all of the work for you, something like jqGrid comes to mind.

Looping through the json result (assuming "points" is what you are looping over)

```
success: function(data){
  jquery.each(data.points, function(index, value){
    //index is the index of the array, value is the actual value
  });
}
```

Look here for using jQuery to modify the DOM: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Comment: I'm basically confused on what the syntax would look like to loop through this object in JQuery or Javascript

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what i wanted